# Protect uploaded files

Tags: php, apache, security

I have build a website based on php/joomla. It is running on a WAMP server.

Users can upload files/images to their own account, and the files are all saved as:

```
public_html/userfiles/0001.jpg
public_html/userfiles/0002.jpg
public_html/userfiles/0003.jpg
...
```

For the sake of privacy, I want to avoid none-registered users or users without permission to access files from other users. Right now, anyone can access all images by entering the filename in the browser address bar.

I need an extremely high level of protection, so my question is: Can I solve this by apache settings? Or should I use fx server site AES encryption and then ask for password at client-site and run descryption with something like [crypto-js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js)?

Comment: You can prevent directory listing using `.htaccess Options -Indexes`

Comment: @Ravi you can still view image if you have the image url and not logged in.

Comment: In other way, what you can do is restrict *.jpg access from `.htaccess` and you can write `.php` script to check user session and based on that you can read and output image from php. `header("Content-Type: image/jpg");`

Comment: So everybody thinks AES encryption would be exaggerated or misplaced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this,

**1. Prevent direct access of .jpg using .htaccess**

**.htaccess**

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg)$">   #all file extensions you want to restrict.
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

**2. Retrive image using `.php` script.**

**get_picture.php**

```
//check here user login
//if not logged-in
// exit();

//proceed if logged-in.

//get picture file path from DB.
$file_path="this/path/will/be/from/db/user_xyz.jpg"

header("content-type: image/jpg"); //set mime type respective to file type

readfile(file_path);

die();
```

**3. how to use in**  
**HTML**

```
<img src="get_picture.php" style="height:100px;width:100px;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really good with .htaccess but you can use the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} allow!=true
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/404.html [L,QSA]
```

What this will do is it will redirect anyone with a cookie **`allow`** not set to **domain.com/404.html**
You should also set http cookie to true while setting it.

Answer (score 0):

This will prevent images being accessed via url, but will still display from html/php file. (change localhost to whatever your host is)

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ - [F]
```